# Shuffling an Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My issue is that i am trying to get the String Array to Shuffle and display the Random List back into the List View. my shuffle is inside my Custom Adapter.

My SongAdapter

```
public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
 public static String[] listSongs = new String[]{}; //String Array of ListSongs#
public void loadFile() {
        try {
            Resources ResFiles = myContext.getResources(); //ResFile is set to getResources,
            InputStream ReadDbFile = ResFiles.openRawResource(R.raw.song); //InputStream is Called to get Text file Songs
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ReadDbFile));
            String DbLines;
            while ((DbLines = reader.readLine()) != null)//While DBlines is not Null keep Reading.
            {
                listSongs = DbLines.split("#");//Dblines is Splitting the Text where # is..
                Model SongModel1 = new Model(); //Call the Model Class
                SongModel1.setName(listSongs[0]);//Set Name from String Array
                SongModel1.setSigner(listSongs[1]);//Set Signer from String Array
                SongModel1.setUrl(listSongs[2]); //Set URL from String Array
                this.add(SongModel1);//Add SongModel String Array to the Model Class
            }
            //Catch any Exception..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void shuffle(){
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(listSongs));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

List Fragment

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {
    static protected SongAdapter adapter;



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        adapter = new SongAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }
```

And Finally i am calling in the ActionBar On Click inside Main class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    static protected SongAdapter adapter;
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.shuffle:
                adapter.shuffle();
               return true;
```

The Error i am getting at Run time is

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dfoley.project2, PID: 1304
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.dfoley.project2.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:135)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:350)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:155)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:74)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:551)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:802)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:596)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:145)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `MenuFragment.adapter.shuffle()` because your `adapter` on your `MainActivity` is different from the other one (which is inside your `MenuFragment`)

As an advice, you should create a public method on your `MenuFragment` that calls `adapter.shuffle()` and call it from your `MainActivity`.

Comment: So i should take that Method out of the Adpater Class and place it inside my MenuFragment then Call that then to the MainActivity

Comment: Not necessarily, you can create that method (called methodA) on your `MenuFragment` and inside that method you call `adapter.shuffle()` from your Adapter. Finally, call from your `MainActivity` your `fragment.methodA`

Comment: Hi I added the `adapter.shuffle` to the `MenuFragment` and then called MethodA inside the `MainActivity` but still show null Pointer but it stop the Application from Crashing.

Answer (score 1):

the `SongAdapter` in your `Fragment` is different from the one in your `Activity`, and only the one in the Fragment is initialized. What you could do is to define a method in your Fragment that calls `array.shuffle()` and call this method when you press on the menu's button